# Big Text File, 75MB, Application taking about an hour to process..Java

Tags: java, performance, file, parsing

I have a text file(.txt) of 75Mb. which has about 3,00,000 lines each line having more about 100 words(50-60 characters each). I need to read about 100 lines and then use some kind of marker to put it at the starting of 101st line, process those 100 lines and clear all the data and then come back to again read from the 101th line,, 
How should I do it? How to keep the markers??

```
   public static void calculateFormulaValues()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\t****************************************calculateFormulaValues()****************************");
        for (CellBean cellBean : Reader.cellList)
        {
            System.out.println("\tCellName="+cellBean.getCellID()+" Time="+cellBean.getHour()+":"+cellBean.getMins());
            LinkedHashMap<String,Double> formulaValueMap=new LinkedHashMap<>();
            LinkedHashMap<String,String> headerValueMap=cellBean.getHeaderValueMap();

        kpiNameLoop:    
            for (String kpiNameToBeCalculated : Reader.kpiAndFormulaMap.keySet())
            {
                String formulaToBeEvaluated=Reader.kpiAndFormulaMap.get(kpiNameToBeCalculated);

                //System.out.println("\n*************Trying to calculate::"+kpiNameToBeCalculated+"="+formulaToBeEvaluated+"***********************************");
                if(formulaToBeEvaluated==null || formulaToBeEvaluated.trim().equals(""))
                {
                    System.err.println("\n************FORMULA-NOT-FOUND-EXCEPTION*******************");
                    System.err.println("\nCellBean-->"+cellBean);
                    System.err.println("KpiToBeCalculated-->"+kpiNameToBeCalculated);
                    System.err.println("Formula Retrieved-->"+formulaToBeEvaluated);
                    System.err.println("************************************************************");
                    System.err.flush();
                    continue kpiNameLoop;
                }
                //^[^\d\W]\w*$
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z_#0-9]+");
                //Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[^\\d\\W]\\w*$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(formulaToBeEvaluated);

                ArrayList<String> myHeaders = new ArrayList<String>();
                boolean result=m.find();
                while(result) 
                {

                    //System.out.println(m.group());
                    myHeaders.add(m.group());
                    result = m.find();
                }

                //System.out.println("HEADSERS(UNSORTED)="+myHeaders);
                TreeSet<String> sortingTreeValues=new TreeSet<>(new java.util.Comparator<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(String str1, String str2)
                    {
                        if(str1.length() > str2.length())
                            return -1;
                        if(str1.length() < str2.length())
                            return +1;
                        if(str1.length() == str2.length())
                            return +1;
                        return 0;
                    }
                });

                for (String headers : myHeaders)
                {
                    if(Character.isDigit(headers.charAt(0)))
                        continue;
                    else
                        sortingTreeValues.add(headers);
                }


                //System.out.println("HEADSERS(SORTED)="+sortingTreeValues);

                for (String counterName : sortingTreeValues)
                {

                    String valueForCounter=headerValueMap.get(counterName);
                    //System.out.println("\tValue For-->"+counterName+"="+valueForCounter);

                    if(valueForCounter==null)
                    {
                        System.err.println("\n*******************************VALUE NOT-GOT EXCEPTION***************");
                        System.err.println("\nCellBean-->"+cellBean);
                        System.err.println("KpiToBeCalculated-->"+kpiNameToBeCalculated);
                        System.err.println("Formula Retrieved-->"+formulaToBeEvaluated);
                        System.err.println("CounterNotFound--->"+counterName);
                        System.err.println("******************************************************************");
                        System.err.flush();
                        continue kpiNameLoop;
                    }

                    if(valueForCounter.trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        valueForCounter="0";
                    }

                    formulaToBeEvaluated=formulaToBeEvaluated.replaceAll(counterName, valueForCounter);
                }

                //System.out.println("FORMULA AFTER REPLACING-->"+formulaToBeEvaluated);
                formulaToBeEvaluated=formulaToBeEvaluated.replaceAll("0.0/0.0", "0.0");
                formulaToBeEvaluated=formulaToBeEvaluated.replaceAll("0/0", "0");
                formulaToBeEvaluated=formulaToBeEvaluated.replaceAll("[0-9\\.]+/0\\.0", "0.0");
                //System.out.println("Formula After Handling Zeros Exception="+formulaToBeEvaluated);

                ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
                ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                String finalValue="";
                try {
                        String resultValue=engine.eval(formulaToBeEvaluated).toString();
                        finalValue=resultValue;


                    }catch (ScriptException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block"40+2"
                        System.out.println("************* ERROR in PARSING Formula******************");
                        System.out.println("FormulaCreated-->"+formulaToBeEvaluated);
                        System.out.println(e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.flush();
                    }

                /*System.out.println("\n************************************FormulaHasBeenCalculated*******************************");
                System.out.println(kpiNameToBeCalculated+"="+formulaToBeEvaluated+"="+finalValue);
                System.out.println("*********************************************************************************************");*/
                formulaValueMap.put(kpiNameToBeCalculated,roundOff(new Double(finalValue),3));

            }

            cellBean.setKpiFormulaValueMap(formulaValueMap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the code to analyze why it is taking that much time

Comment: Keyword: buffered input/output streams

Comment: use count with Scanner.readLine();

Comment: @Sunny, I have posted the code, this is the code that is applied on the data read from the file;

Comment: You appear to be running a Javascript and creating regular expressions for each block of text.  I suggest you make the code more efficient, you should be able to process 75 MB in few seconds and make the code much simpler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, Actually I have some formulas to evaluate, for this I first use regex to find all the operands in the formula, and then replace them by their corresponding values in the formula, Also to evaluate the formula thus formed I am using the inbuilt JavaScript Engine. This process needs to happen to each row(3,00,000 rows), If there is some other way around , pls suggest.